# Is there any difference between referencing a object's variable id and using 'this'?

Tags: javascript, object, reference, this

Having the following code, where both `fc`1 and `fc2` methods should return the value of the `x` property inside the object they build and return (and not from the Foo instance):

```
function Foo() {
  this.x = 5;
}

Foo.prototype.fc1 = function() {
  return {
    x: 6,
    getx() {
      return this.x;
    }
  }
}

Foo.prototype.fc2 = function() {
  const o = {
    x: 6,
    getx() {
      return o.x;
    }
  }
  return o;
}
```

Is there any internal or relevante difference between methods fc1 and fc2 in regards to using  or referencing the constant identifier from inside the object like it is done in fc2?
Im leaning towards fc2 pattern because seems more clean to me (using `this` for only one thing sounds good to me!). Performance is not an issue, but in any case, would be good to know if some considerations must me taken in relation to it.

Not an native english speaker, let me know if i'm not being clear. Also, couldn't make the right search in google. I didn't land in any usefull article. Articles or documentation of help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, there different.  Fc2 is using a closure.  As such is prevented from been used with `bind` / `call` etc.  So in some respects gives your class more protection / encapsulation.  It also means you can pass the function without using `bind`

Comment: I'm sure simeone will give a better and proper answer, but "this" refers to the object that is calling the function "this" is in, in this case "o". So "this" referes to the caller of getx which is "o". If you had another object inside "o" having the getx function, this would refer to the inner object instead of "o" so you have to be careful. I don't remember correctly, but I think from Ecmascript 6 and up, using the short syntax for function delcarations using <> will make "this" keyword behave differently and makes it refer to the most outer object, but I don't remember this very well.

Comment: We better wait for a good answer. 2 years ago I would have been able to answer to this properly.

Comment: @Keith Didn't know it was a closure too!

Comment: @Lorthas In fc1, <this> refers to the object the method is building, and not the Foo instance (using the short synthax, both methods works as I spected though)

Comment: I have forgotten all this a bit, to be honest. I hope someone gives a full answer with examples, I used to have a good knowledge of Javascript but it is 3 years without touching it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second example your using a closure.

The closure is over `o`.. This means `this` is not even used.  It does have advantages though, it's a trick you can use to create protected Objects / Encapsulation etc.

For an example, below I have made your example into a working snippet.   I then make a reference to the `getX` function in both cases, and then call it.  You will notice the first 1 returns undefined, but the second one because you are using a closure still returns `6`.

Of course the disadvantage is that `call` `apply` & `bind` will have no effect on the function too.  Which one you choose of course depends on how you want to use the function, in your example using the `closure` seems a more robust option.  In theory the `closure` will possibility have a slight performance benefit too, this is because `this` has something called a prototype chain, and this can slow things down..

```js
function Foo() {
  this.x = 5;
}

Foo.prototype.fc1 = function() {
  return {
    x: 6,
    getx() {
      return this.x;
    }
  }
}

Foo.prototype.fc2 = function() {
  const o = {
    x: 6,
    getx() {
      return o.x;
    }
  }
  return o;
}


const f = new Foo();

console.log('calling foo.fc1.getx');
const fc1 = f.fc1().getx;
console.log(fc1());

console.log('calling foo.fc2.getx');
const fc2 = f.fc2().getx;
console.log(fc2());
```

Comment: I'm not following why f.fc1().getx() returns 6 but storing f.fc1().get inside fc1 and calling it returns undefined. Thanks!

Comment: @EmilioGrisolía  It can sometimes take a little while to crack it.  But basically the second one returns `6`, because  `o.x` is always `o.x` as it's now a closure, and in this case it's `6`.   On the first one we loose `this` content, it's now pointing at `window / global`, and `window.x` is `undefined`.

Comment: What i'm not gettin is what causes `this` to be lost in the case of fc1. I really appreciate your help by the way, thank you.